# Taking a screen shot with Samsung Android Gear Live (Wear)

Tags: wear-os

I just received a Samsung Android Wear from I/O today, and started working with it as soon as I got back to the hotel. I was wondering if anyone else (or an official rep) knows how to take a screen shot of the device.

Comment: I used same solution mentioned in the answers here. I wrote a blog post about it for future reference: http://blog.thetechtime.com/post/90086107707/how-to-take-screenshots-in-android-wear-based-smart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

If you're running Android Wear 5.0.1 or later and have the updated Android Wear app on your phone, it's now very simple to take a screenshot of your watch. Just open the menu and tap "Take wearable screenshot" as shown below.

[image: Take wearable screenshot from Android Wear phone app]

**Taking a screenshot over ADB (the harder way)**

You can use adb to grab a screenshot. Something like:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png
```

This will first put screenshot.png on the watch's SD card, and then copy that screenshot to your current working directory. It is more complicated than the updated answer above, but will work for any Android Wear device, regardless of version.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a device yet, so I don't know the exact steps, but I've heard you can take screenshots through the developer tools, which you can access via 
Settings>About and tap on the build number,just like you do on your phone.

Found here: http://www.androidcentral.com/just-get-android-wear-these-are-first-10-things-you-need-know

Comment: Ha, yup just turned that on. Thanks! Tap the build number 7 times and you get the "You are now a developer!" message. I'll have to give the screencap stuff from Tony a shot here in a minute too.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Tony Wickham's answer, I made a script for it:

https://gist.github.com/michaelsanford/029eef643f49e409ddf3

Write up with notes [is here](https://medium.com/@msanford/taking-android-screenshots-652d6794f679).

You can install the above gist with

```
cd /usr/local/bin & curl -o ./gcap https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michaelsanford/029eef643f49e409ddf3/raw && chmod +x gcap
```

Here is a trivial excerpt, the gist above is much more complete:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -e
ETIME=$(date +"%s")
adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screen-${ETIME}.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen-${ETIME}.png screen-${ETIME}.png
adb shell rm /sdcard/screen-${ETIME}.png
```

Call it something short, `chmox +x` and symlink it to `/usr/local/bin` for easy use. My personal version is modified to adb pull to `~/Desktop/screen-${ETIME}.png` because I use OS X.

Note that you will first need to [enable debugging](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/07/05/how-to-android-wear-enable-debugging-take-screenshots-unlock-the-bootloader-and-root-the-lg-g-watch/).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to take screenshots on a wearable is to use the Android SDK `monitor` tool:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/monitor
```

After enabling USB debugging on the wearable simply launch `monitor` and use the screenshot button shown here in the upper-right:

[image]

Comment: This is what worked for me. Had permission issues writing the screenshot.